# What does this phrase refer to?

Tags: dialogue, uncut-gems

In the 2019 film *Uncut Gems*, Demany and Kevin went to Howard's shop and Demany was disappointed to find that Howard was not selling watches

> **Howard:** That's not my problem, man.
>   **Demany:** That ain't your fucking problem? He don't like shit in this dusty, tinfoil-filled bitch.

What's does the phrase *"dusty, tinfoil-filled bitch"* refer to in this?

Answer (score 2):

He was talking about the jewelry display case.  tinfoil would be a derogatory term for cheap jewelry.  Dusty, obviously, meaning unkempt.  The "bitch" part is just some anger coming through, like if someone was trying to sell you a knockoff watch at full price you might say something like, "Get that bitch away from me".

So, a dirty display case filled with cheap jewelry, to someone who's angry, would be called a "dusty tinfoil-filled bitch".